# Trim ffmpeg screen capture while recording

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to record my screen. Once the recording gets longer than 30 seconds I would like to start trimming the begining of the video while still recording to keep the total video length constantly at 30 seconds. This way I can always be recording, and when I end the recording it will only be the most recent 30 seconds.
My ffmpeg command:
`-hide_banner -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -rtbufsize 256M -framerate 60 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 60 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -y "output.mp4"`
I have tried  `-t 30.0` but that just ends the recording after 30 seconds.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a script (a scrip that deletes the older recordings). You may use `segment` muxer: Replace `"output.mp4"` with `-segment -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 30 output%06d.mp4`. It keeps creating 30 seconds video files. You need some script running at the background that keeps deleting the older recorded files.